# How to select gridview row by simple click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I select a row clicking anywhere on that row in gridview? Which gridview event would suit it?

Comment: There is no event for clicked somewhere in the row. Use the method you would usually use, such as a select button, and attach listeners to the row to trigger the button with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-to-use feature. But [this guy](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2006/01/07/14576.aspx) explains how to do it.

You basically have to extend the DataGrid class and add the event RowClicked to it.